# Python extract files from zip

Tags: python, python-itertools, zip

trying to make a simple password brute force to unzip a .zip archive in python, im using permutations to try every possibility with 2 caracteres(my idea is use more permutations in the future), and also i set up a .zip file with 2 characteres password. But my program just dont extract the files from the zip.

```
import zipfile
from itertools import permutations
import re

z1 = input("Enter with file path+filename.zip:")
z = zipfile.ZipFile(z1)

caracteres = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'o', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't', 'u', 'v', 'w', 'x', 'y', 'z', 'A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'I', 'J', 'K', 'L', 'M', 'N', 'O', 'P', 'Q', 'R', 'S', 'T', 'U', 'V', 'W', 'X', 'Y', 'Z', '0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9']

for i in permutations(caracteres,2): 
    i = re.sub(r'\W',"",str(i))
    print(i)
    password = i.encode()
    try:     
        z.open(z1, mode='r')   
        z.extractall(pwd=password)
        print ("pass="+i+"\n")
        exit(0)
    except Exception:
        pass
```

Comment: How do you know you got the correct password?

Comment: i made a zip file with the password: 90
but the script dont extract the files from the zip

Comment: Does it work if you remove all the permutation logic and pass the string directly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Permutations assumes that the objects in the list can only be used once.  So given your list of characters, passwords like "aa" can never appear.  If that happened to be your test password, it would never match.  `itertools.product` may be a better choice.

```
>>> list(itertools.permutations("ABC", 2))
[('A', 'B'), ('A', 'C'), ('B', 'A'), ('B', 'C'), ('C', 'A'), ('C', 'B')]
>>> list(itertools.product("ABC", repeat=2))
[('A', 'A'), ('A', 'B'), ('A', 'C'), ('B', 'A'), ('B', 'B'), ('B', 'C'), ('C', 'A'), ('C', 'B'), ('C', 'C')]
```

Your next problem is that you don't seem to be calling `z.open()` properly.  This would be used to extract a particular file from the archive.  But you're passing in `z1`, which is the zipfile object, not a name.  Further, you're not supplying a password.  So this call will fail every time, preventing the later extraction from starting.  I think you need to get rid of the `z.open()` line entirely.